# why change value in 1 object can change all value another object?

Tags: php, arrays

i found this problem accidently when i want to answer someone question XD

```
<?php
/*
why change value in 1 object can change all value another object?
*/

function prints($a)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($a);
    echo "</pre>";
}

//CASE 1 : create object from array
$array = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'albert'
);
$data = array(
    (object) $array,
    (object) $array
);
prints($data);
/*output
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => albert
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => albert
        )
)
*/


//CASE 2 : change value 2nd object of 2nd array 
$data[1]->name = 'john';
prints($data);
/* output
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => albert
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => john
        )
)
no question about this. 
only 2nd object of 2nd object will change
its know this clearly
*/

//create same object with different way
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->id=1;
$obj->name='albert';
$data= array($obj, $obj);
prints($data);
/*output: this will be same as $data array in above
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => albert
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => albert
        )
)
*/

//THE PROBLEM
//change value 2nd object of 2nd array 
$data[1]->name="john";
prints($data);
/*output
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => john
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => john
        )

)
All key name in object will change to john , instead of only the 2nd.
How this could happen??
*/

?>
```

> Re explain the problem

in **CASE 1**: i try to change last object value (albert) into (john). And the result is only last array will change to (john). **[I KNOW THIS]**

IN **CASE 2**: i produce same array with different way, then i try the same thing like in  **CASE 1**. But the result is all of [name] changed to [john], instead of let the [name] in object 1 as (albert), and change the [name] in object 2 as (john)

i struggle to know about this, but still cant found the answer from google.
i found some, but still cant explain clearly to me ^_^7

i very appreciate from any explanation. thanks

Comment: What is the problem.  You create and filled an array, you then created a second array and filled it with the previous array and converted them into objects.  What is wrong with that?

Comment: Objects are assigned by reference by default. So in your second example you use the same object which point to the same data. Also see the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: @Rizier123 can you re explain about your answer with an example, because i still didnt get it. i will appreciate your help

Comment: @plonknimbuzz [**An image says more than a thousand words**](http://imgur.com/a/3Y5Hz). In the second example both objects point to the same data in memory.

Comment: thanks man @Rizier123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The answer from @Rizier123

IN CASE 2: i create array from **SAME OBJECT**:  $data= array($obj, $obj);

IN CASE 1: i create array from **DIFFERENT OBJECT**: $data= array($obj1, $obj2);

Yes, it's like similar in display, but not in computer memory

```
$data = array(
    (object) $array, //computer maybe save it as $obj1 or any variable that i dont know the name XD
    (object) $array //computer maybe save it as $obj2
);
```

So this is the final code explaination

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'albert'
);
$obj1= (object) $array;
$obj2= (object) $array;
$obj3= (object) $array;
//CASE 1
$data = array($obj1, $obj2); //different object although it have same component

//CASE 2
$data = array($obj3, $obj3); //same object

?>
```

THANKS @Rizier123

Answer (score 0):

I know tihs is a dated question but in case it helps I'll post a possible solution for this behavior of php.
Just clone the object in every array index using `clone` php keyword. It's like creating a new instace of the initial object for every index. Then you can access to any index and edit the object and only that object in that index will reflect the changes

```
<?php

$p = (object)[
    'Name' => 'Jhon Doe'
];

$a = [
    clone $p,
    clone $p,
    clone $p
];


$a[1]->Name = 'Peter Doe';


/**** Output using clone keyword *****
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["Nombre"]=>
    string(8) "Jhon Doe"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["Nombre"]=>
    string(9) "Peter Doe"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
    ["Nombre"]=>
    string(8) "Jhon Doe"
  }
}

**** Output without clone keyword
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["Nombre"]=>
    string(9) "Peter Doe"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["Nombre"]=>
    string(9) "Peter Doe"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["Nombre"]=>
    string(9) "Peter Doe"
  }
}
*/
```